# Python - 2 arguments instead of one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, illegalargumentexception

Python Code:

```py
class Importer:
    from importlib import __import__, reload
    from sys import modules

    libname = ""
    import_count = 0
    module = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.libname = name
        self.import_count = 0

    def importm(self):
        if self.libname not in self.modules:
            self.module = __import__(self.libname)
        else:
            print("must reload")
            self.module = self.reload(self.module)
        self.import_count += 1

# test out Importer

importer = Importer("module")

importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello (again)
print(importer.import_count)
```

The above Python (3.8.1) code is at [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/SkCBRtf2w), which if you run, will give an error:

```
TypeError: reload() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When I open up the `importlib` library in Python, I see this:

```py
# ... (previous code; unnecessary)

_RELOADING = {}


def reload(module): ## this is where reload is defined (one argument)
    """Reload the module and return it.

    The module must have been successfully imported before.

    """
    if not module or not isinstance(module, types.ModuleType): ## check for type of module
        raise TypeError("reload() argument must be a module")
    try:
        name = module.__spec__.name
    except AttributeError:
        name = module.__name__

    if sys.modules.get(name) is not module: ## other code you (probably) don't have to care about
        msg = "module {} not in sys.modules"
        raise ImportError(msg.format(name), name=name)
    if name in _RELOADING:
        return _RELOADING[name]
    _RELOADING[name] = module
    try:
        parent_name = name.rpartition('.')[0]
        if parent_name:
            try:
                parent = sys.modules[parent_name]
            except KeyError:
                msg = "parent {!r} not in sys.modules"
                raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
                                  name=parent_name) from None
            else:
                pkgpath = parent.__path__
        else:
            pkgpath = None
        target = module
        spec = module.__spec__ = _bootstrap._find_spec(name, pkgpath, target)
        if spec is None:
            raise ModuleNotFoundError(f"spec not found for the module {name!r}", name=name)
        _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
        # The module may have replaced itself in sys.modules!
        return sys.modules[name]
    finally:
        try:
            del _RELOADING[name]
        except KeyError:
            pass

# ... (After code; unnecessary)
```

**All double hashtag (##) comments are mine**

It is clearly visible that `reload` DOES have 1 argument, and it checks if that argument is a module.  In [the OGDB (OnineGDB) code](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/SkCBRtf2w), I am only passing one argument (pretty sure) and it is of type module (most likely).  If I remove that argument (you can edit the OGDB), it gives:

```
TypeError: reload() argument must be module
```

So for some reason, Python keeps thinking I have one more argument than I do actually have.  The only way I made it work was editing the `importlib` file to have `reload` have two arguments (not a good idea).

I tried running PDB, not helpful.

Can anyone spot anything obviously wrong, like actually having two arguments?

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question.

Comment: When you call it like `self.reload`, it implicitly adds `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Replace `self.reload` with `reload`. The reason it works in the first place is because you import inside the "class scope", which I would consider bad practice.

Comment: @mkrieger1 : I have linked an [Online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/SkCBRtf2w)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But you should add the code **in the question**. Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: @L3viathan : By doing that raises a `NameError: name 'reload' is not defined`

Comment: @LakshyaRaj Do your imports outside the class.

Comment: @L3viathan : Thank you.  That worked 

Comment: @L3viathan : there's still one thing that I don't understand: why does it say anything about the arguments when the solution was about something completely different?

Comment: @LakshyaRaj That has to do with the fact that functions are descriptors and their descriptor behaviour. Too complex to discuss in a comment here, but if you are that interested, I can explain it in chat.

Comment: @L3viathan : OK I've opened [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225877/discussion-between-lakshya-raj-and-l3viathan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do is put the `import`s outside the class for it to work.  Here is [the new OGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/fork/H1CHV9f3D).  Credits to [@L3viathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268686/python-2-arguments-instead-of-one#comment115388700_65268686).  Code below:

```py
from importlib import __import__, reload
from sys import modules

class Importer:
    libname = ""
    import_count = 0
    module = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.libname = name
        self.import_count = 0

    def importm(self):
        if self.libname not in modules:
            self.module = __import__(self.libname)
        else:
            print("must reload")
            self.module = reload(self.module)
        self.import_count += 1

# test out Importer

importer = Importer("module")

importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello (again)
print(importer.import_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue because you're calling `self.reload(self.module)`, which is actually equivalent to calling `reload(self, self.module)`. To see this, try running the following:

```py
class Example:
    def some_method(*args):
        print(args)
    def some_other_method(self):
        self.some_method(1)

an_example = Example()
example.some_other_method()
```

You should see that this prints out 2 arguments, not 1, (the first of which is a reference to `self`) despite us only passing one argument to `some_method`, and `some_method` having no `self` argument.

It would be better to import the `reload` method within your `importm` method (or outside the class altogether!), like so:

```py
    def importm(self):
        from importlib import __import__, reload
        if self.libname not in self.modules:
            self.module = __import__(self.libname)
        else:
            print("must reload")
            self.module = reload(self.module)
        self.import_count += 1
```

Comment: i dont think you actually need to import reload ... I could be wrong though

Comment: @JoranBeasley : `reload` is a function in `importlib` so I need to include it

Comment: @user14749127: your first example does not apply to me because the `reload` function is not inside a class that `self` would have to do anything about it.

Comment: oh you are apparently right ... in python2 you did not need to import it... I guess in py3 that changed

Comment: @JoranBeasley I believe it needs to be imported in Python 3

Comment: @LakshyaRaj that's exactly the point I'm illustrating! :) When you import the function in the class scope, it will be treated as a class member, like `some_method`.

Comment: @user14749127 : Oh OK.  I thought it meant that that `self` was the reason for 2 arguments.  Your second example is good though.

Answer (score -1):

```
import mymodule

reload(mymodule)
```

is how it would work ... Im not sure what your question is from that big wall of text above  this is typically used to reset state to its initial state

**mymodule.py**

```
x = 5
```

**main.py**

```
from importlib import reload # in py2 you did not need to import it
import mymodule
print(mymodule.x) # 5
mymodule.x = 8
print(mymodule.x) # 8
reload(mymodule)
print(mymodule.x) # 5 again
```

Comment: you may not have noticed, but the code in my question is used to reimport a module multiple times.  Just doing once as in your example defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: you can do it where ever you want ... as many times as you want ... this was simply showing you how to use reload

Comment: Oh OK.  That makes sense.